# Bootstrap-slider.js and class not working

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, slider

I am trying to create a page with two sliders.  The user selects values using the slider, the script dispalys the values chosen by the user, and also simply multiplies the two values by each other and some factors.  Simple.  This is my code.  The issue appears to be when I use `class="ms-slider"`.  Without it, the formatting is lost, but the script doesnt work with it.

```
<form method="post" action="#">
//Slider #1
<input type="range" class="ms-slider" name="viewers" id="value1" value="0" min="0" max="200000" step='1000'  data-highlight="true" onchange="calc" data-slider-ticks="[0, 100000, 200000]" data-slider-ticks-snap-bounds="3" data-slider-value="10000" data-slider-ticks-labels='["0", "100,000", "200,000"]'/>
//Slider #2   
<input type="range" class="ms-slider" name="price" id="value2" value="0" min="0" max="16" step='1' data-highlight="true" onchange="calc" data-slider-ticks="[0, 8, 16]" data-slider-ticks-snap-bounds="3" data-slider-value="8" data-slider-ticks-labels='["$0", "$8", "$16"]'/>
    
//output fields - displays slider values
   <input type="text" id="value11" name="value11"/>
   <input type="text" id="value21" name="value21"/>
    
//output fields - displays the values multiplied   
   <input type="text" id="total1" name="total1"/>
   <input type="text" id="total2" name="total2"/> 
    
</form>


<script>
// On any change in form.
$("form :input").change(function() {
    // Fetch selected options.
    var value1 = $('form #value1').val();
    var value2 = $('form #value2').val();
   
       
    // Output to text field.
    $('form #value11').val((value1));
    $('form #value21').val((value2));
    $('form #total1').val((value1 * value2) * 0.01);
    $('form #total2').val((value1 * value2) * 0.05);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Your code works as provided, `.ms-slider` is not part of bootstrap

Comment: Thanks...any way to make the script work with .ms-slider?

Comment: It does work because you have not added any css for `.ms-slider`. In your example the presence or absence of the class makes no difference.

Comment: Please provide a *complete reproducible* example.

Answer (score 0):

Two `id` values are not unique (`value1` and `value2`). The first definitions are in the `range` `input`s. Here are the duplicates:

```
  <input type="text" id="value1" name="value1"/>
  <input type="text" id="value2" name="value2"/>
```

What I am trying to say is the problem you have is that two sets of tags have the same `id`s: `value1` and `value2`. There are two tags with `id` `value1` and two tags with `id` `value2`. All `id` tags should be unique in order for your code to work.

Comment: What I am trying to say is the problem you have is that two sets of tags have the same ids: value1 and value2. There are two tags with id value1 and two tags with id value2.

Comment: Thanks - I made those changes and edited my question to reflect the changes.  But my problem still exists.  If I remove the class="ms-slider" however, the script works (even with the double ids). However, when I do that I lose the formatting.